# KeyError for an object value that is in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

Can someone explain why 'Louisville' is returning a KeyError? It is in the data frame from what I understand. What am I missing?

Here is what the data looks like. It is a CSV.

[image: data]

This is what `off_data.head()` looks like

[image: off_data.head()]

`off_data.index()`

[image: off_data.index()]

`off_data.columns`

[image: off_data.columns]

```
off_data[0:2].to_dict()
```

[image: off_data[0:2].to_dict()]

Rajith Thennakoon's Suggestion

[image: Rajith Thennakoon's suggestion]

```
{'Conf': {'Michigan St. ': 'B10', 'Louisville ': 'ACC'},
 'AdjTempo': {'Michigan St. ': 70.4, 'Louisville ': 67.8},
 'AdjOE': {'Michigan St. ': 114.4, 'Louisville ': 113.9},
 'eFG%': {'Michigan St. ': 52.9, 'Louisville ': 60.7},
 'TO%': {'Michigan St. ': 15.9, 'Louisville ': 17.1},
 'OR%': {'Michigan St. ': 37.1, 'Louisville ': 32.8},
 'FTRate': {'Michigan St. ': 30.9, 'Louisville ': 32.5},
 'AdjDE': {'Michigan St. ': 85.1, 'Louisville ': 87.5},
 'deFG%': {'Michigan St. ': 40.3, 'Louisville ': 42.9},
 'dTO%': {'Michigan St. ': 20.7, 'Louisville ': 15.9},
 'dOR%': {'Michigan St. ': 25.0, 'Louisville ': 27.6},
 'dFTRate': {'Michigan St. ': 27.3, 'Louisville ': 26.0}}
```

Input

```
import pandas as pd

off_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\westc\Desktop\sports.data\ncaab\kenpomdata\off20.csv', index_col= 'Team')

type(off_data)

off_data.loc["Louisville",0]
```

### Output

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2896             try:
>   -> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898             except KeyError:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Louisville'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> > KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in 
> >           4 
> >           5 type(off_data)
> >     ----> 6 off_data.loc["Louisville",0]
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> >     **getitem**(self, key)    1416                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):    1417                     pass
> >     -> 1418             return self._getitem_tuple(key)    1419         else:    1420             # we by definition only have the 0th axis
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> >     _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
> >         803     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
> >         804         try:
> >     --> 805             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
> >         806         except IndexingError:
> >         807             pass
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> >     _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
> >         927         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
> >         928             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
> >     --> 929                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
> >         930 
> >         931                 # we have yielded a scalar ?
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> >     _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1848         # fall thru to straight lookup    1849         self._validate_key(key, axis)
> >     -> 1850         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)    1851     1852
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in
> >     _get_label(self, label, axis)
> >         158             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")
> >         159 
> >     --> 160         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
> >         161 
> >         162     def _get_loc(self, key: int, axis: int):
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key,
> >     axis, level, drop_level)    3735             loc, new_index =
> >     self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)    3736
> >     else:
> >     -> 3737             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)    3738     3739             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):
> >
> > ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> >     get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2897                 return
> >     self._engine.get_loc(key)    2898       `

Comment: Can you clean up the error message so that only the KeyError and whatever the other "Error" type was is showing?

Comment: try this `off_data.loc[0,"Louisville"]`

Comment: what is the 0 supposed to represent?

Comment: @rajiththennakoon if they made 'Teams' the index, then that makes no sense

Comment: show us what the df looks like after you've read it in, along with off_data.index and off_data.columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the row by:

```
off_data.loc[off_data['Team'] == "Louisville"]
```

The way your doing the location, requires the column name, which by your output appears to be Team, you could try these to see if they work:

```
In [4496]: df2.loc[0,"Team"]                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4496]: 'Michigan'

In [4497]: df2.loc[1,"Team"]                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4497]: 'Louisville'
```

Looks like there is whitespace in the data, here's a quick way to strip the whitespace at the end:

```
off_data.index = off_data.index.str.strip()
```

which should let you do a search as is:

```
off_data[off_data.index == 'Louisville']
```

Comment: @westcollins hmm, can you provide a "off_data[0:2].to_dict()" to examine?

Comment: just added under other pictures

Comment: It seems like Team and Conf are merged, if you can put that to_dict value as text enclosed in ```   ```  I could probably read it in and figure it out

Comment: let me know if that was what you were asking for

Comment: oh, no i meant the actual data so i can copy/paste it into a dataframe on my side, i can't from the pictures

Comment: oh gotcha, see above. It's right above where 'Input' starts

Comment: I see one issue, your team names have a space in them: "Louisville " that affects the search. There are a few things you can do here, i'll post them

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
off_data.index = off_data.index.str.strip()
off_data.loc[off_data.index == "Louisville"]
```

**EDIT**

if you need to remove spaces when read the dataframe.you can use [skipinitialspace=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).This will **Skip spaces after delimiter.**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(.. skipinitialspace=True)
```

Or need to remove spaces of a particular column,you can use like this

```
df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].str.strip()
```

Or you can use pandas [rstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) or [lstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html#pandas.Series.str.lstrip) as well.

lstrip,Strip whitespaces (including newlines) or a set of specified characters from each string in the Series/Index from left side.

rstrip,Strip whitespaces (including newlines) or a set of specified characters from each string in the Series/Index from right side.

Comment: see above where I added a picture of your suggestion

Comment: i guess leading and trailing spaces are the issues..check the updated answer

Comment: thank you very much. The issue was just trailing spaces :/. do you have a solution to stripping trailing spaces w/o turning off_data into an index?

Comment: @westcollins check the detailed answer,i guess it will answer your question mentioned above